# log4j how to avoid "unknown source" message

Tags: java, log4j

Am using my java application with log4j as logging mechanism

For most of the debug statements of the 3rd party jars am using, am getting filename with line numbers like
com.abc.xyz.GG(doFilter:67)

but for my source code, am getting the following
com.xyz.abc.class (unknown source problem)

Its tough for me to debug my source code since there is no line number info.

Can Someone please help me how do I enable this....

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you compile your code with the "-g:none" option of javac?
If so, the compiler doesn't generate any debugging information and Log4j cannot fetch them.

Comment: Do you use javac by hand, or do you compile your code through an IDE ? Through an IDE, you should check that option like "Generate debugging info" is well checked in the compiler settings...

Comment: Hi guys; I know it's been a couple of years, but I'm compiling by hand, without the -g:none option, and I'm getting "Unknown Source" what else could it be?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `-g` option when calling the `javac` command.
From the Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html):

> -g
>   Generate all debugging information, including local variables. By default, only line number and source file information is generated.

If you using ant to build your project you need to set the javac task's `debug` attribute to `on`, like this:

```
<javac debug="on">...</javac>
```